# JQuery animate scrollTop Not Working Properly

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

The following JQuery code scrolls the page to the first error in the form:

```
$('html,body').stop().delay(500).animate({scrollTop: $errors.filter(":first").offset().top -30},'slow');
```

However, if I replace the `$('html,body')` with the name of a container element such as a div class `$('.myDivClass')` with fixed positioning, it doesn't seem to work well. It just scrolls to random places up and down with each submission. If the container element is anything other than html,body, it doesn't seem to work right.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The css of the container element looks like this (so you know what I mean):

```
.mcModalWrap1{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
padding:50px;
background-image:url(images/overlay.png);
overflow:auto;
z-index:999;
display:none;
}
```

I have tried using position() instead of offset() for relative positioning but it didn't make a difference.

Thank you!

**Update: Looks like there is no solution for this.**

Comment: In what browser are you seeing the behavior? In Chrome 17 it appears to work fine. When I submit the form it scrolls to the first error. If the first error is the name then it scrolls to the top of the page. If the first error is further down, then it scrolls me to the input element.

Comment: In all of my browsers it does the same thing. IE, FF, Chrome, Opera. The inline version works perfectly fine though.

Comment: @Jasper, Is it not moving alternatively up and down for you?

Comment: For scrolling inside of container... try this nifty jQuery plugin... very flexible! http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 13):

I know I'm super-late to the party, but ran into the same issue, and here's how I fixed it.

When scrolling inside a fixed-positioned element, for some reason you have to add it's own scrollTop to the position to which you want to scroll, so:

```
var position = $errors.filter(":first").position().top + $('. myDivClass').scrollTop()
$('.myDivClass').animate({ scrollTop: position })
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It works only on first call.

To fix this you need to scroll to the top everytime before calling animate().

So I changed my:

```
$(element).animate({scrollTop: 500});
```

with

```
$(element).scrollTop(0);
$(element).animate({scrollTop: 500});
```

Yes, it's true, everytime it scrolls to the top first, but without animation and works quite well for me.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are scrolling something other than the window then you need to find the error's position relative to its container. In this case a div. If the element is in the div then use `position` instead which will be in reference to the first parent with relative, fixed or absolute positioning.

```
$('.mcModalWrap1')
     .stop()
     .delay(500)
     .animate({scrollTop: $errors.filter(":first").position().top -30},'slow');
```

Comment: Using position() instead of offset() yields the same result for me.

Comment: @user1108996 I know you have linked to your site before but I can't find the link on this question. @mrtsherman, the posted CSS shows that the element in question is basically full-screen, it's at-least docked at the top of the page, so `offset().top` and `position().top` should return the same value.

Comment: @Jasper Ok, I added the link back to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by dumping the idea. JQuery scrollTop does not work in parent container other than html,body to scroll to a particular position. It only works to scroll to top or bottom. Neither position() nor offset() calculates the value properly.

If someone has an answer, I'd love to know.

Comment: Probably need 100% height or use clearfix if you have used floats ... google clearfix should be easy :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to substitute this line of code to see if it behaves like what you want:

```
$('#container').stop().delay(500).animate({scrollTop: $errors.filter(":first").offset().top - $('#container').offset().top + $('#container').scrollTop()},'slow');
```

You can replace the part `$errors.filter(":first").offset().top - $('#container').offset().top` by `$errors.filter(":first").position().top`, I believe.