# jQuery onScroll() show and hide DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple onScroll function, which shows a DIV when the scroll (down) height is 100 for example, and then if scrolled up soon as it reach 100 it hides the div, works perfect.

However, if I scroll down quickly and while its showing the DIV if I quickly scroll up & down 2 three times, it doesn't catch the event, even if its up again, it still shows the DIV, but again if I scroll even 1 pixel down, it hides it and if reaches 100 then it shows DIV again.. I hope I made it clear, I dont have an online demo as I am working on localhost.. below is my function that I am using standalone in the template within just <*script> tag..

```
  jQuery(document).scroll(function ($) {

      var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();    
      var hoffset = 100;

      if (y > hoffset) {
          // show div
      } else {
          // hide div
      }
  });
```

Can someone please guide me to right direction, what other best approaches can be done for this, basically I am doing this for header nav div..

regards

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this? See my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MFUw3/1379/)

I use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` instead.

Comment: hi urbz, even on your example, if you quickly scroll down and up, the right scrollbar where the DIV fadesIn and out, scroll it up-down quickly 6-7  times, and you will notice then even if you stop it continues to fadein and fadeout, it must stop. Thats the problem I am having..

Comment: This depends on the height of the `body` and the height of the `div`. In my Fiddle example, try setting the height to `750px;` and you will see a difference. I've read somewhere though that several browsers has problems with this particular scroll animation, like so from this scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235167/jquery-animate-scrolltop-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to stop animation, while its in the process is below and works..

```
 jQuery('.thedivclass').stop(false, true).slideDown();
```